# How do I create a COM accessible .NET Class that references DAO?

Tags: vb.net, vba, com, ms-access-2007, dao

I am trying to create a .NET class library that is accessible in a VBA project I am building. I would like to be able to pass a dao.recorset object to a public function in my .net class library as a parameter.

My code is similar to

```
Public Sub PassDaoItem(item as DAO.recordSet)
    TODO: [Code Here]
End Sub
```

When I use regasm to register the object I receive the following error:

```
Error

: Type library exporter cannot load type 'DAO.Recordset' (error: System.IO.FileN
otFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.DAO, Version=5.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5db0597a00edd538' or one of its dependencies. T
he system cannot find the file specified.).
```

Are there any suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to use dao recorset in .net code just add reference to dao:
In VS open the "Solution Explorer" > "Reference" > "Add Reference" > ".Net", you should see the component "dao".

E.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\dao.dll.

Access VBA code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rec As DAO.Recordset

  Set db = Application.CurrentDb
  Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")

  Dim dotNetObject As New COMAccessibleTest.ReadData
  dotNetObject.GetData rec

  rec.Clone
  db.Close
End Sub
```

C# code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace ReadDataTest
{
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("772de12c-3ade-4f43-9981-fd3c39691520")]
    public interface IReadData
    {
        void GetData(ref dao.Recordset data);
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("2acf2296-63b0-47b2-ab77-51c4e35e7365")]
    [ProgId("ReadDataTest")]
    public class ReadData : IReadData
    {
        public void GetData(ref dao.Recordset data)
        {
            var lines = new StringBuilder();

            data.MoveFirst();
            while (!data.EOF)
            {
                lines.AppendLine(data.Fields[0].Value + "," + data.Fields[1].Value + "," + data.Fields[2].Value + "," + data.Fields[3].Value);
                data.MoveNext();
            }

            var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\Temp\\test.txt");
            file.WriteLine(lines);
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is absolutely correct. I have no problem implementing DAO in my .NET project. My problem is passing the dao.Recordset object from VBA to a .NET class. My error is raised when using REGASM to create the type libraries.

Comment: Aha I see. And did you try to check the checkbox on your project properties 'Register for COM interop'? This does not work for you?